# SQL within a computed field

Tags: commerce

I've created a *computed field* with some php code in it.

Now I want to use some sql, so I can run this *query/php* command inside computed field :

`$number =db_query('SELECT COUNT(distinct field_percentage_value) FROM content_field_percentage WHERE nid = {nid} and vid = {version} ORDER BY vid DESC');`

Edit: In some case when I type `nid = ${nid}` and `vid=${version}` and edit a content type, as a result I get a blank page.

It was supposed to grab a *nodeID*, *versionID* and order it in descending order, but it doesn't.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Please reconsider. Code in database (that's what computed field really is) is already not so good practice. Calling a database in it is even riskier. Isn't it time for custom module? Also, "but it doesn't" is pretty vague. Could you write what actually happened, and what query was generated? If you don't know, use [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to find out - you probably already have it if you write code.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This site is not for suggestions; please ask an explicit question. Notice that `{nid}` is considered a table name from the database API. Variable replacements are not possible in a single quoted string; that is why `${nid}` doesn't work.

Comment: Is it still bad, if the computed field's code is in a module function? When the goal could be to achieve database stored field values, which need dynamic re-computation. (computed_field_YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME_compute())